# How can I update weekly data in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create a weekly performance overview of machines. The data is  saved outside of the weekly Excel workbook in 12 workbooks, one for each month of the year.

To reduce the data I only present the data of the week with lookup functions depending on the dates.

- The first problem is that I have to manually update the data (e.g. november 21 -> december 21:  ...\machine-data\21-11.xls -> ...\machine-data\21-12.xls).
  To update the data I use a Replace function in a macro to update the files but as you can imagine it takes too long (range is about 1000 cells).
- The other problem is that some weeks belong to two months so I can't use the Excel built-in refresh button for each month.
  [image: e.g. in the picture]

This is the actual VBA code (for the simplification in the picture):

```vb
Sub updateMonday()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Range("C3:C4").Replace Cells(7, 3), Cells(8, 3)
    End With
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I created a macro for every day of a week.

The best-case would be a VBA function which knows which weekdays to update and is much faster than my code. Is it possible to work with arrays?

Comment: So basically, you need to update the external workbook path in the lookup formula based on the day of the current week when you open the workbook?

Comment: Yes this is true but it don't have to be when I open the Workbook. The week could be chosen with a Dropdown menue for each week of a year

Comment: Well your question is not related to the `dropdown menu` part but it is possible to get the dates for a given week and all you then need to do is to format the date to the format of the file name (`yy-mm`) and replace the formula. So do some research on how to get date range based on week number, attempt it then come and ask a question about it if you are stuck @msfld

Comment: I already got this, the problem is that I have to write 7 macros to update the days of the weeks. In addition to this the Replace code is so slow. It takes at least 1 minute for one macro

Comment: I just did a quick test using your code and the replacing 1000 cells takes only few seconds (3-4seconds) so I'm not sure if there are some other factors to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understand, with that `replace` operation you are updating links to external file from old week/month to new week/month.  I have a similar weekly task and I am using below macro to update links in it.  I hope an adoption of this macro will save you considerable time.

```
Sub Link_update()

Sheets("MainItems").Activate
reportingDate = Cells(3, 10).Value

Dim term As Date
term = InputBox("Enter the term as date", "Enter the term ", Format(reportingDate, "dd.mm.yyyy"))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 11, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 11, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", _
    NewName:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 4, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 4, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 10, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 10, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", _
    NewName:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 3, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 3, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 9, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 9, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", _
    NewName:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 2, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 2, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 8, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 8, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", _
    NewName:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 1, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 1, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term - 7, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term - 7, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", _
    NewName:="C:\Temp\" & Format(term, "yyyymm") & "\TemplateFile" & Format(term, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     
End Sub
```